# Count the ones in select row of cells but skip the elevens

Tags: excel, count, unique-values

[Example Data & Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce97G.png)

I have a row of data and I want make a count on a specific subset of cells that contain the value of 1.

I want to ignore numbers that do not have a value of 1 even though they may contain ones such as 11, 21, 120 etc.

There are no negative values involved.

In the example provided my data subset would be:

(B3,C3,I3,J3,P3,Q3) or specifically (1,1,2,1,8,11) --> there are 3 ones.

My expected results for cell V3 would be 3 because there are 3 ones in the set of data. 11 has been ignored.

First post so link to ImgURL

Thank you.

Comment: Try `countif()`?

Comment: I see where I created confusion. That's typical of me. The columns and rows I need to analyze and count ones in are:   B3,C3 and I3,J3 and P3,Q3   for a lot of columnar data.       Sorry @esch. I misled you.

Comment: I don't think I have that syntax correct. =COUNTIF(B3,C3,I3,J3,P3Q3) returns 'too many arguments' Thanks @findwindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be thinking of applying one COUNTIF to a complicated range.
But you don't need to - you can apply the COUNTIF three times to simple ranges and add together:
`=COUNTIF(B1:C1,1)+COUNTIF(I1:J1,1)+COUNTIF(P1:Q1,1)`

Comment: Thank you @zsalya that is the solution.  
=COUNTIF(B3:C3,1)+COUNTIF(I3:J3,1)+COUNTIF(P3:Q3,1)  

It's not necessary but (B3:C3,"=1")works as well. Thank you all. Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIF(F3:U3, 1)` should work

Comment: Thank you esch. I appreciate the response. That's not quite it. It's the range that is causing my headache. It's not actually a range of cells, it's a collection of columns B,C,I,J,P and Q in Row 3. Thanks though. I guess it could even be called a collection of three different ranges: (B3:C3) and (I3:J:3) and (P3:Q3).